# stick a sprite to another when it collide with it

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, sprite, accelerometer

so I have a sprite that is created every second  and that is moving at a random position (sprite1) and another sprite that has a fixed position (sprite2). I would like that when sprite1 collide with sprite2, sprite1 is like sticked to it (it stops moving and is sticked to it) . How can I do this please ? sorry for my english I'm french :/

p.s : sprite2 is rotating with accelerometer, so if sprite1 collide with it I would like that it rotate too :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can try to use box2d to do this. It will help to detect collisions and to manage rotations, movement, etc.

Comment: but instead of going on box2d can I create a shape of my sprite with gl and so it is not a rectangular shape

Comment: in box2d you can choose any form you want for your object's physical body.

Comment: yes but my shape is just a circle so I don't think I need box2d for just a circle

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can do it simply in Cocos2d.

1) First set the rect for sprite1 and sprite2 using `CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)`

2) As you told sprite1 is moving at random position and sprite2 is fixed to particular position, you can check them collide by using `CGRectIntersectsRect([sprite1 bounds],[sprite2 bounds])`.

3) if it intersects, set `sprite1.position = sprite2.position`

Note: you said sprite1 is rotating, rect can be fit only to the regular bodies. if you want exact collision or physical properties for sprite better you can go for box2d.

Comment: but instead of going on box2d can I create a shape of my sprite with gl and so it is not a rectangular shape

Comment: i didn't worked on GL. but you can get the shape of a sprite in box2d using third party tool such as Physics Editor(http://www.physicseditor.de/), etc.

Comment: yes but my shape is just a circle so I don't think I need box2d for just a circle

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Box2d (which can handle circle collisions), you can try something like this:

1.) Detect collision, is the distance between the two circles center point (x,y), less than the sum of the two circles radius.

2.) Make the Sprite1 stick to Sprite2,  Stop the movement of Sprite1, and save the relative delta (x,y) to Sprite2, then whenever Sprite2 moves or rotates apply the same delta movement and rotation to Sprite1.